# PHP: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error for this PHP code

```
syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
```

It says line 2, which is the include line:

```
<?php  
  include 'config.inc.php';  
  
  // initialization  
  $photo_upload_fields = '';  
  $counter = 1;  
  
  // If we want more fields, then use, preupload.php?number_of_fields=20  
  $number_of_fields = (isset($_GET['number_of_fields'])) ?  
    (int)($_GET['number_of_fields']) : 5;  
  
  // Firstly Lets build the Category List  
  $result = mysql_query('SELECT category_id,category_name FROM gallery_category');  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
    $photo_category_list .= <<<__HTML_END

<option value="$row[0]">$row[1]</option>\n  
__HTML_END;  
  }  
  mysql_free_result( $result );    
  
  // Lets build the Image Uploading fields  
  while($counter <= $number_of_fields) {  
    $photo_upload_fields .= <<<__HTML_END  
<tr><td>  
  Photo {$counter}:  
  <input name="photo_filename[]"  
type="file" />  
</td></tr>  
<tr><td>  
  Caption:  
  <textarea name="photo_caption[]" cols="30"  
    rows="1"></textarea>  
</td></tr>  
__HTML_END;  
    $counter++;  
  }  
  
  // Final Output  
  echo <<<__HTML_END  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Lets upload Photos</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  
  action="upload.php" method="post"  
  name="upload_form">  
  <table width="90%" border="0"  
    align="center" style="width: 90%;">  
    <tr><td>  
      Select Category  
      <select name="category">  
      $photo_category_list  
      </select>  
    </td></tr>  
    <! - Insert the image fields here -->  
    $photo_upload_fields  
    <tr><td>  
      <input type="submit" name="submit"  
        value="Add Photos" />  
    </td></tr>  
  </table>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>  
__HTML_END;  
?>
```

My include file looks like this:

```
<?php  
  $mysql_link = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");  
  mysql_select_db("db_name") or die("Could not select database");  
  $images_dir = "photos";  
?>
```

**Solution:**

I had invisible unicode characters hidden in the code which caused the PHP parser to complain of the above syntax error.

Comment: "more or less"? The error seems to be related to the included file, so it would be better to know more about it than less.

Comment: Remove (comment out) the include-line to see if this line trigs the error or not.

Comment: You might have an invisible character (a special space or similar) somewhere there. You could try to remove the offending line and rewriting it.

Comment: Check if u forgot to put " somewhere in your config file

Comment: Try (include 'config.inc.php');

Comment: @WilliamIsted: that will not work

Comment: @felixking by "more or less" i mean i only replaced my actual user, password and server name.  Theres nothing else different about that file.

Comment: Woops Typo. Try include ('config.inc.php');

Comment: When i comment out line 2, the error moves to the next line.  So, I started deleting the empty spaces, and the error keeps moving down the page.  I think @Juhana is correct-- I have invisible characters and just need to re-write the whole thing. THANK YOU!

Comment: I found that when copying some sources from internet to text editors, characters "looking like" spaces are actually 0xA0 rather than 0x20, which cause this error!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple spaces at the start and the end of your HEREDOC syntax variables; this leads to problems. Remove the spaces after

```
<<<__HTML_END
```

and after

```
__HTML_END;
```

and your code should be working.

See also this thread where I found the answer: http://board.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10333424

Comment: _It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters... That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon._ ... **If this rule is broken ... it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line.** [Heredoc - PHP: Strings - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 4):

Delete the first few lines and rewrite them.  Sometimes if you copy and paste code, it can insert unicode invisible characters, which aren't parsed correctly by PHP. So it throws this error. It's happened to me several times.

Answer (score 0):

just ensure you have closed all you " and ' in the file you are including. usually this error is pointed to the first line in the file.

Answer (score -2):

Use the inclue as: `include("config.inc.php");` for right syntax.

Comment: This is a matter of personal preference, not "right syntax."  Include (like require, echo, and many others) is a language construct, not a function, therefore parentheses are not required and it's fine to omit them.